# How to return a dynamic object from a generic function - error

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two generic functions. In the first one I fill a dictionary and then call the next generic function to convert the dictionary to object.

Here I need to return to the `T` generic object rather than specifying to a particular one. I am not able to achieve this. It shows error:

> The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter "T" in the generic method or type..

```
public T Fill<T>()
{
    Dictionary<string,string> d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    //filled dictionary -----
    SomeClass dObject = ToObject<SomeClass>(d);

    //[---Here I need to return a dynamic object rather than fixing to SomeClass--]
    T dObject = ToObject<T>d); ///* Not able to acheive this *///

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(dObject, typeof(T));  
}

private T ToObject<T>(IDictionary<string, string> dict)
    where T : class,new()
{
    T t = new T();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetType().GetProperties();
    //--- code to convert object to dictionary         
    return t;
}
```

Comment: You need to add the `class` and `new()` constraints to the `Fill<T>` method so that it matches the `ToObject<T>` function.

Comment: I have added it now  - public T Fill<T>()where T: class,new() but it s still the same error

Comment: No, now you have a different error because `dObject` is declared twice.

Comment: Oops sorry, its working fine ! Thanks a bunch .. Really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `ToObject` method is constrained with `class` and `new()`, you also need to match that to your `Fill` method.

```
public T Fill<T>() where class, new()
```

However, there doesn't appear to be a need for the `class` constraint so you can remove it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code you have a constraint that `T` must be a `class` and it must have a parameterless constructor (`new`):

```
private T ToObject<T>(IDictionary<string, string> dict)
    where T : class,new()
```

Your `Fill` method's signature is like this:

```
public T Fill<T>()
```

See there are no constraints which means I can pass a `struct` or any other type to it, even a type which does not have a parameterless constructor. This is why you are getting the error. You need to define the same constraint or something more specific than the constraint you have defined on `ToObject<T>` method. To fix your issue, simply do this:

```
public T Fill<T>() where class, new()
```

Now `Fill<T>` has the same constraint so I can only call it with a class who has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Sorry about that.. Didn't know how it works . I have deleted the answer

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)